# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined in angularjs with polymer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer-1.0

I'm getting the following error when rendering polymer templates from inside angularjs view.

$scope.descriptions is populated through a http GET request as following:

```
$http.get('http://api.fundsofhope.org/projects/all').success(function(data) {
  $scope.descriptions = data;
})
```

And here is the template, which shows the error.

```
<div id="cards" ng-repeat="items in descriptions">
    <div class="card-wrap">
        <paper-card id="paper-card" heading="{{items.title}}" image="../images/1.jpg" elevation="1"  ng-click="play(items)">
                <paper-fab class="paper-fab" icon="home" elevation="1" ng-click="donationPage(items)"></paper-fab>
                    <p class="cardDetail">
                        {{items.description}}
                    </p>

                    <paper-dialog id="dialog" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="scale-down-animation">
                            <div id="image">
                                <img src="../images/1.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div id="dialogContent">
                                    <h2 class="dialogInfo" id="dialogName">
                                        {{items.ngo.name}}
                                    </h2>
                                    <h2 class="dialogInfo" id="dialogCost">
                                        {{"Cost : " + items.cost}}
                                    </h2>
                                    <h2 id="dialogStatus" class="dialogInfo">
                                            {{"STATUS : " + items.status}}
                                    </h2>
                                    <h2 id="dialogStart" class="dialogInfo">
                                            {{items.startDate}}
                                    </h2>
                                    <h2 id="dialogEnd" class="dialogInfo">
                                            {{items.endDate}}
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="descriptionBox">
                                        <p class="dialogInfo" id="dialogDetails" maxLength="50">
                                            {{items.description}}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </paper-dialog>

                <paper-progress value="50" ></paper-progress>
                <paper-progress value="{{items.status / items.cost}}" ></paper-progress>
        </paper-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Surprisingly, this error is encountered only in Chrome (v52). While in Firefox and Microsoft Edge, this error is not thrown but Polymer does not render at all!

Here is the Angular's base template which has the polymer components included:

```
<head>
    <title>fundsofhope</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="1095141978516-uqea8udtat0463k3ukomrj1obouacggv.apps.googleusercontent.com">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../angularJS/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../customScripts/mainController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../customScripts/dataController.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html">

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/animations/scale-up-animation.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/animations/scale-down-animation.html">

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

    <link href="../src/home.html">
    <link href="../src/loading.html">
    <link href="../src/paperCardList.html">
    <link href="../src/donationPage.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styleSheets/sheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="indexDiv1" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?